# Which screen resolution (Largest or smallest) is best for developer hand-offs?

Tags: design, screen-resolution, developer, hand-off

I am currently designing a web app to cater for the following screen resolutions:

1. 1920 x 1080
2. 1600 x 864
3. 1366 x 768

I'm wondering:

- Which is the default/primary resolution I should design in for developer hand-offs. (It's a huge web app and I can't possibly replicate it in all the resolutions.)
- What trade-offs am I making, or what precaution should I take if I select 1 resolution over another. (I'm currently inclined to design in 1366x768 since it's easier for developer to imagine scaling up)

Comment: 1600 x 864? What kind of resolution is this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer really depends on your application design. The main question is:

**Will the design be *different* depending on the resolution?**

So for example, will the app be responsive? Will some elements only show if there is enough space for them?

If the answer to the above question is **yes**, then you will need to provide a separate design for each different scenario. Not necessarily every possible resolution, but each resolution where the UI will have a significant change to it.

If the answer to the above question is **no**, then it really doesn't matter which resolution you design in as long as each element of the design is clear enough as to how it should expand/contract. In this case, I would suggest picking a resolution somewhere in the middle (i.e. what you expect the average user to have).